# Why do we need to create a one-arg constructor in order to use temporary nameless objects?

Tags: c++, constructor

Alright, so I was studying about nameless temporary objects in operator overloading where instead of writing:

```
Classname temp;
temp.variable=variable;
return temp;
```

You could do this:

```
return Classname(variable);
```

But to do this, you also need to create a one-argument constructor like this:

```
Classname(int c): variable(c)
{ }
```

My question is.. why do we need to create this one-argument constructor? I've been searching online a lot and can't find any reason. So, I really need your help guys. Thanks.

Comment: Because you're invoking it. That's the meaning of what you wrote.

Comment: How do you expect the returned `temp` will hold the value `variable` or `c`? Assigment, constructor, aggregate initialization, choose one.

Comment: @user207421 can you explain please? I'm sorry I'm new to this and I don't understand it

Comment: @Ripi2 The reason I'm confused is because when we are not using nameless temporary objects and using the 3 lines of code that I have written in the start we don't need one arg constructor but when we use nameless temporary object, we need it. why?

Comment: Those 3 lines use default ctor (i.e. constructor, I suppose you don't define your own not-argument ctor), then assigment. The second snippet uses just ctor.

Comment: @Ripi2 ah okay, I get it now. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I said as well?

Comment: @user207421 I'm sorry I didn't get what you meant by invoking. sorry english isn't my native language. But now that I think about it, yes you basically said the same. Sorry. And thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to. You can use [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) instead:

```
struct Classname {
    int variable;
};
// ...
return Classname{42};
```

This creates an object of the class whose only non-static member is initialized with the value 42.

Aggregate initialization is subject to some restrictions. The logic is that only types that are in some sense analogous to C structs---being groupings of data with no invariants---should be eligible. If you make the type more complicated, by adding constructors, or hiding some members through access control, your intent is probably that the members shall not be initialized directly without going through some constructor or some setter methods. So in that case, it is not allowed; instead, an appropriate constructor must be defined.

Comment: oh yes. The program was using private data member where variable was declared private. Anyway, can you explain why are we using the one argument constructor?

Comment: also your code uses struct but the code I was seeing was using class in it

Comment: @ZainAbedin As I said, any class with private members needs to be initialized using a constructor, because, when you declare members private, you are sort of saying that maybe not all possible values are valid, or that some action should occur when those members are set; so the language prevents you from initializing them directly with the aggregate syntax. By the way, structs and classes are the same in C++, except for the default visibility of their members.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks for the answer. But I'm having trouble understanding in why are we using one arg constructor witht this(I'm sorry I know you are trying really hard to help and I'm not understanding it). The reason I'm confused is because when we are not using nameless temporary objects and using the 3 lines of code that I have written in the start we don't need one arg constructor but when we use nameless temporary object, we need it. why?

Comment: @ZainAbedin The `Classname(variable)` syntax calls a constructor with `variable` as an argument. Therefore, if you choose to use this syntax, then there needs to be an available constructor that can take that argument.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks a lot man. Now, I get it. I was really freaking about this (It's 4 AM here haha). so thanks a lot for the help.